# How to avoid this CCRC error when creating a view?

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

Can you creat a view in CCRC if stream is locked ?
It seems others can create a view but this one guy is getting an error when trying to create the view:

```
problems performing ClearCase operation

Problems were encountered while retrieving view synchronization information and data

ClearCase CM server: Error: unable to begin update session: unknown error in view server.
ClearCase CM Server: Error: Additional information may be available in the view log on host "hostname".
ClearCase CM Server: Error: operation "view_ws_begin_load_session" failed: unknown error in view server
```

Any ideas on how to fix or trouble shoot this?
(CCRC is on Windows XP SP3 laptops)

Answer (score 0):

No the stream isn't locked.

Looking at the views log on the server can tell you more, but typically, you can have error due to access rights (like the primary group incorrectly or not set in the CCRC GUI).
Or there is some kind of *server* error (the CCRC being the view server for all the web views: the `view_server` process for that particular view could have an issue)

So check the CCRC server logs for views (see [`getlog`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_getlog.htm)):

```
 cleartool getlog -host CCRC_servername -since yesterday view
```