# Error occurred while performing the joint operation in IBM

Tags: java, clearcase

Getting java code of UCM Stream from the IBM clearcase tool in local machine is an easy task. But this time I am facing the issue in getting it.

I followed the following procedure.

```
Selecting the project-->
right click on it -->  
click on the 'joint project' option
```

A popup appears on the screen where it is setting and creating a development stream with view tags and copy area path name. Clicking on next takes us to the ' create integration view'. Click on finish and select the appropriate project from the drop down. It is processing successfully till half path but after that it is throwing the following exception.

```
'**Error: "IOException: Error storing: "the whole local path where code is getting copied\.copyarea.db.new".
Unable to rename file "the whole local path where code is getting copied\.copyarea.db.new" to "the whole local path where code is getting copied\.copyarea.db": Unknown error.."**
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of ClearCase and your environment, especial an heterogeneous one (Windows client for creating views, view storage stored on Unix).

For instance, it can be a [Samba share access issue](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013880206).

Try to look at as many logs as you can to see if any other error messages are there which could convey some clues, using [`getlog`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_getlog.htm) (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13867431/6309) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24308061/6309)), or launching the ClearCase Administration Console (`ccadminconsole.msc`).

The Windows Event viewer can help too.