# Not able to add file on source control

Tags: clearcase

I try to add to source control a file, and get:

```
Error adding 'M:\niyazmom_SYN_AUG_ASIA_NONASIA_WASHBOOK\bo_goit_synthetic_pb\Synfiny\Development\Executables\MDI\frmRegionMappingBrowser.frm' to source control.

Error from VOB database: "\bo_goit_synthetic_pb".
```

How can I avoid/diagnose this error?

Comment: You might consider such errors to be a case to migrate to some other version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your exact ClearCase version and on the *full* error message.
For instance, [this documentation](http://www.samecs.com/how_do_i/ClearCase_VOBs/ClearCase%20VOBs%20how%20do%20I.htm#_Toc245769748) mentions:

```
cleartool: Error: Error from VOB database: "\test_vob".
cleartool: Error: Trouble opening VOB database: "\test_vob".
cleartool: Error: Not a vob object: "vob:\test_vob".
```

The main point to check is the various logs (both local and on the clearCase server) [using `cleartool getlog`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13867431/6309).